# Rolling Update with Kubernetes Deployment without increasing the cluster size

Tags: google-compute-engine, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a cluster that can only run one Pod per node due to our configuration (sometimes Kubernetes will randomly run two on one pod but w/e). Any time I have to update my Deployment which causes a Rolling Update, Kubernetes will simply never finish the update.

The reason for this appears to be that there isn't enough room in the nodes to deploy the new pods from the rolling update.

Now, some of you may say that I may simple increase the cluster size every time I want to perform an update. The problem with that approach is that I have enabled autoscaling on the cluster and the Deployment `replicas` is set high so that Kubernetes [automatically scales with the cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36985242/204263). This means I can't change the cluster size to accomodate the Rolling Update.

How can I perform a Rolling Update with this configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Can you set [maxSurge](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#max-surge) to 0 and [maxUnavailable](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#max-unavailable) to some positive value?